# angular2-nvd3 error: groups.watchTransition is not a function

Tags: angular, d3.js, ng2-nvd3

I've an angular website with some charts made with angular2-nvd3. i recently upgrade all my dependencies and since then I have this errors:

```
ERROR TypeError: groups.watchTransition is not a function
    at SVGGElement.<anonymous> (nv.d3.js:13130)
    at d3.js:962
    at d3_selection_each (d3.js:968)
    at Array.push../node_modules/d3/d3.js.d3_selectionPrototype.each (d3.js:961)
    at Array.chart (nv.d3.js:12775)
    at Array.push../node_modules/d3/d3.js.d3_selectionPrototype.call (d3.js:975)
    at SVGGElement.<anonymous> (nv.d3.js:6621)
    at d3.js:962
    at d3_selection_each (d3.js:968)
    at Array.push../node_modules/d3/d3.js.d3_selectionPrototype.each (d3.js:961)
ERROR TypeError: bars.watchTransition is not a function
        at SVGGElement.<anonymous> (nv.d3.js:8286)
        at d3.js:962
        at d3_selection_each (d3.js:968)
        at Array.push../node_modules/d3/d3.js.d3_selectionPrototype.each (d3.js:961)
        at Array.chart (nv.d3.js:8041)
        at Array.push../node_modules/d3/d3.js.d3_selectionPrototype.call (d3.js:975)
        at SVGSVGElement.<anonymous> (nv.d3.js:8682)
        at d3.js:962
        at d3_selection_each (d3.js:968)
        at Array.push../node_modules/angular2-nvd3/node_modules/d3/d3.js.d3_selectionPrototype.each (d3.js:961)
```

I needed to make many changes due to breaking changes in the last rxjs, so I realy would like to find a solution without rolling back everything. Main changes are about angular and rxjs versions.
Does someone have an idea?

Here my previous package.json:

```
 "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^6.0.0-beta.15",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/material": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.1",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "^3.0.2",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-markercluster": "^1.0.0",
    "angular2-nvd3": "^1.0.7",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.6",
    "d3": "^3.5.17",
    "flex-layout": "^1.0.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "leaflet": "^1.3.1",
    "leaflet.markercluster": "^1.3.0",
    "nvd3": "^1.8.6",
    "rxjs": "^6.1.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
```

And the new one:

```
   "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^6.0.0-beta.18",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.7",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "^3.1.0",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-markercluster": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.1",
    "angular2-nvd3": "^1.0.7",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "d3": "^3.5.17",
    "flex-layout": "^1.0.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "leaflet": "^1.3.4",
    "leaflet.markercluster": "^1.4.0",
    "nvd3": "^1.8.5",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it could help someone, i solved my problem with :

1. deleted node_modules folder
2. npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
3. npm cache clean --force
4. npm i -g @angular/cli
5. npm i

Probably an old dependency in the node folder..